# non-numeric argument to binary operator in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is driving me crazy... Sorry if it is trivial. I Searched but did not find help. First of all a reproducible example

```
df = data.frame(idx = c(1,2,3,4,5), label=c(0,0,1,1,0), 
 filter = c(1,1,0,1,1), values = c(0.1, 0.3, 1.2, 1.7, 2.4))


ggplot (df, aes(x = df$idx, y = df$values, size = as.factor(df$label*filter), 
color = as.factor(df$label*filter)))+geom_point()+
scale_colour_manual(name = "Duplicates (J/N)", labels = c("Nein", "Ja"), 
values = c("red", "blue")) + scale_size_manual(name = "Duplicates (J/N)", 
labels = c("Nein", "Ja"), values = c("red", "blue"))
```

When I run this example I get the error

```
Error in coords$size * .pt : non-numeric argument to binary Operator
```

Now usually in ggplot you get this error when you got too many + or not enough +. But it does not seem to be the case here. At least is not evident to me.

This is working (without the `scale_size_manual`)

```
ggplot (df, aes(x = df$idx, y = df$values, size = as.factor(df$label*filter), 
            color = as.factor(df$label*filter)))+geom_point()+
    scale_colour_manual(name = "Duplicates (J/N)", labels = c("Nein", "Ja"), 
                  values = c("red", "blue"))
```

Anyone spot the mistake??

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the values you are passing to scale_size_manual c("red", "blue") are characters and not numeric values. scale_size requires numeric values.

Comment: That was it! Thanks. You saved me ;-) I will accept your answer as such as soon as I can (System says in 7 min)...